# Dynamically binding numbered objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, adobe-edge

I have DOM-objects that are numbered from 1-10 as so: checkbox_1, back_arrow_1, checkbox_2, back_arrow_2. When the arrow is clicked, I want it to perform the click function of the checkbox-object with same name, for instance

```
back_arrow_1 clicked
-> $(checkbox_1).click();
```

I am dynamically binding the click functions for the back_arrow's as so:

```
(function(){ 
   for (var ar_num = 1; ar_num < 4; ar_num++){
          $("back_arrow_"+ar_num).bind("click", function () {       
          $("checkbox_"+ar_num).click();        
       }); 
   }

})();
```

And console.logging() shows that it does bind the correct arrow, but when I click any of the arrows, it does the click function for the checkbox_4, which is because I assume that instead of bind the "checkbox_1" for example, the browser performs the event of checkbox_+ar_num, getting the number that the for loop left ar_num at.

What would be the correct way to perform this functionality?

Comment: You don't need a for loop. What is `back_arrow_1`, an ID?

Comment: $("#back_arrow_"+ar_num) may work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a closure, that will save the value of ar_num after your loop is over in your click function.

Look at this : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/psDYs/1/)

```
for (var ar_num = 1; ar_num < 4; ar_num++){
    (function(num) { 
        $("#back_arrow_"+num).bind("click", function () {       
            $("#checkbox_"+num).click();     
        });
    })(ar_num);
}
```

Comment: Yup, this worked. Coming from a AS3 background I am still not totally used to working with JS scope/closures, thanks!